# Match hyphenated floats

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working on JavaScript code, and I need to extract float or int numbers between hyphens. Like this:

```
var string="someText-180.5-200.70-someOtherText";
```

I need to get:

```
var number1="180.5";
var number2="200.70";
```

Comment: Start with `string.split('-')` and see what you can come up with.

Comment: try http://www.rubular.com/ - it lets you play with regexs very nicely.

Comment: @acheong87 actually, I don't ask anything if I've not tried for hours before.

Comment: @Blender great! I didn't think about the simplest solution. thanks! and thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

While other RegExp based solutions work, I'm going to propose a solution that does not use regular expressions. 
My motivation for this is that regular expressions can be difficult to read, modify and/or debug sometimes.

This code returns an array with all the floats from the string (assuming the floats are positive)

```
"someText-180.5-200.70-someOtherText".split("-"). //splits by hyphens
 map(function(elem){
    return parseFloat(elem);//convert each part to float
}).filter(function(elem){
   return elem===elem;//filter out the not-a-numbers,
                      // that is, stuff converting to float failed on
});
```

This could also be done without `map/filter` in a less 'functional' way if you're more comfortable with that. I believe code readability is *very* important and you should feel comfortable with your own code. You can do

```
var str = "someText-180.5-200.70-someOtherText";
var splitStr = str.split("-");
var arrayOfFloats = [];
for(var i=0;i<splitStr.length;i++){
   var asFloat = parseFloat(splitStr[i]);
   if(asFloat===asFloat){ //check for NaN, that is parse float fails
      arrayOfFloats.push(asFloat);   
   }
}
//now arrayOfFloats contains all the floats in your expression
```

If you would like not to match the first and last parts (that is, only floats that are strictly *between* hyphens) elements you can `slice` them first :)

Comment: What "above solution"?  If you're referring to another answer, you need to be more specific.  Are you talking about [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15289221/20938)?

Comment: @AlanMoore To be honest I looked through both solutions, none really covered OP's specification exactly, for example, the one you referred to does not check for hyphens. I wanted to illustrate the case that even if this is possible using regular expressions I do not think it is the best approach, and I suggested an alternative solution to OP's problem. I've edited my answer to be more clear, thank you for noticing.

Comment: I was making a meta-comment about screen geography, pointing out that you can't count on other answers being above or below yours.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Like I said, I was relying on that, you caught me :-)

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems is, that a regex matches this: "-180.5-" , than the next match will be searched in "200.70-someOtherText" string so, when the next search run wont match 200.70 ...
We should do a bit more than write a regex.

In my soultion, i cuted the examined part of the string, and run regex again on the other part of the string.. and do while there is matching.

See below the code:

```
    function findAllINeed(str){
         result = [];
         while ((match = /(?:\-)(([0-9]+)\.?([0-9]*))(?:\-)/.exec(str)) != null) {    
             str = str.substr(match.index + match[1].length)
             result.push(parseFloat(match[1]));
         }
         return result; 
    }
```

I tried this:

```
    findAllINeed("someText-180.5-200.70-someOtherText sd sdf -6 -6.777 7- s 4.55 -4-sdfsdfsdf -45.77-4-")
    [180.5, 200.7, 4, 45.77, 4]
```

Does not match -6, -6.7777, 4.55, 7- ...

But find all Positive float or integer between '-' characters
I hope this helped you out.

Comment: +1 If you'd like to go for a RegExp solution and not one based on pure string manipulation, this is the one I'd recommend.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following **regex** to accomplish what you are looking for:

```
[0-9]*\.?,?[0-9]+
```

---

### Input:

- someText-180.5-200.70-someOtherText

### Output:

- 180.5
- 200.70

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
var string="someText-180.5-200.70-someOtherText";

var match = string.match(/.*?(\d+(\.\d+)?).*?(\d+(\.\d+)?)/);
console.log(match[1]);  // prints 180.5
console.log(match[3]);  // prints 200.70
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var numbers = string.match(/[\d.]+/g)
```

Or if you're concerned about multiple periods creating invalid numbers:

```
var numbers = string.match(/\d+(\.\d+)?/g)
```